# Implementing a tabbed Windows dialog window in C

Tags: user-interface, tabs, windows

Background:
I’ve inherited a project, about 10k loc implementing an odbc driver. To configure the driver a configuration window is opened. The configuration window is defined by an .rc file (a resource script) which defines all the buttons and checkboxes using x,y coordinates.

Up until now when adding a new feature I just copy/pasted another button/checkbox changing the variable names and ID codes, this worked pretty well. As of late the panel has gotten too monolithic, and it has been decided that the configuration panel should be overhauled. The new design will segregate options into tabs, instead of having them all on one page.

Problem:
I need to figure out how to implement a Windows dialog window with tabs. I have googled around, tried to find examples, and had no luck trying to figure this out. I can open the .rc file in visual studio (the project was NOT originally developed in visual studio) and it shows me a nice visual representation of the config panel, I can drag the elements around, and it modifies the .rc file nicely. What I can’t figure out how to do is get tabs to work. I can create a tab control, but I can’t do anything with it. I can’t figure out how to put other objects on the different tabs of the tab control.

What I am ideally looking for is an extremely terse example implementing this (a dialog window with at least two tabs and at least one thing on each tab) in C. From that point I can abstract the rest. If that can’t be found a pointer to a comprehensive tutorial on how to implement a tabbed dialog box would probably be the next best thing. I’ve found tutorials in C#, but the rest of the driver, which interfaces with the configuration panel, is written in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are explanations and examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486050(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: +1 If @TheGeneral won't accept your answer, and tries to claim it as his own, then you can have an up vote from me as consolation!

Comment: @David Heffernan: That's not really an issue for me. I'd rather say I'm worried about the OP's apparent lack of ability to quickly discover information from online documentation, which is undoubtedly an invaluable quality for a developer, these days. Thank you for the upvote anyways :)

Comment: It's as if Stack Overflow was created and web search suddenly stopped working, in the minds of so many

Answer (score 0):

Answer was found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760551(v=vs.85).aspx but examples needed some hacking to get them to work.

Comment: That's the same link that @SirDarius gave you!! You should have accepted his answer and it's not too late to do so!